# How do I get the minimum or maximum of two values for each row in a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a list of standard errors and standard deviations by date, like so:

```
date        avg_stdev   avg_sterr
2016-11-25  0.02345404  0.009561593
2016-11-27  0.02098070  0.009600404
2016-11-28  0.02098070  0.009600404
2016-11-29  0.02098070  0.009600404
2016-11-30  0.02009983  0.008637851
2016-12-03  0.01793612  0.008303243
```

I want to create two new columns that are the higher and the lower of those. (So in each of these particular rows, `avg_stlow` would equal `avg_sterr` and `avg_sthigh` would be `avg_stdev`, but the values will cross later on.)

I tried doing `dt[,avg_stlow := min(avg_stdev, avg_sterr)]`, but this just gives me the minimum value from the columns. I also tried `dt[,avg_stlow := if(avg_stdev > avg_sterr) avg_sterr else avg_stdev]`, but this seems to determine which column is less (by some means) and use that column throughout. How can I get it to evaluate based on the value for each row?

Comment: It's the strangely-named `pmin` and `pmax` you need, I guess.

Comment: Yes! This is it. (Stick it in as an answer and I'll mark it.)

Comment: Glad it works. I think this linked Q&A covers it.